# Flask-WTF form with a variable number of fields (a list of items)

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I've a form to create a cocktail recipe. It has some common fields like name, description and others, and also a list of ingredients. An ingredient has an ID (foreign-key for a table of ingredients), as the value of a `select` tag, a name and a *quantity* numeric field, as user input. At first, in the HTML there is only one field for an ingredient; if the user want to add another ingredient to the recipe, a button 'Add ingredient' create another field, just after the previous one.

How can I manage this kind of form with WTForms and Flask-WTF, in a Python/Flask backend?
My problem is: how can I say in the form class "there is this list that must have at least one item (an ingredient), and no maximum" so that I can properly insert the recipe into database?

Edit:

This is my 'add new drink' form. There is no 'ingredients' field because that's what I can't do.

```py
class AddDrinkForm(FlaskForm):
    drink_id = HiddenField("ID")
    name = StringField("Name", validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=1, max=255)])
    description = TextAreaField("Description", validators=[Optional(), Length(min=1, max=512)])
    submit = SubmitField("Save")
```

This is the form on the client-side. There is at least one ingredient field, with a select menu and a textbox to specify it's quantity.
[image]

If I click on "Add ingredient" this happens:
[image]

With JS, I create another field for another ingredient with the same structure. If I click again, it add a new ingredient and so on. The question is the same: how should I structure my (WTF-)form to include this (not predefined) number of ingredients?

Comment: Can you add another string field to your flask form for "ingredient".  Set it up as the one ingredient field that renders on first page load.  User clicks "add ingredient" x times.  Add a javascript function that runs on "save" click before submitting data to server.  This function would collect additional field values and concatenate (with a delimiter) and put all the values in the one wtform-field.  Then on python side, parse the string formatted list back into a real list.

Answer (score 0):

maybe create a 3rd table?

```
Table 1 (Cocktail Table):
cocktail_id
cocktail_name

Table 2 (Ingredients Table):
cocktail_id
ingredients_name

Table 3 (Cocktail Ingredients Table):
cocktail_ingredients_id
cocktail_id
ingredients_id
quantity
```

Then for a given cocktail, search table 3 for all results of cocktail_id. 
You can inner join the other tables to get the ingredient name or cocktail name when needed.

When uploading to database, you would just need to create a new entry for each cocktail ingredient you're saving to the cocktail ingredients table; with the cocktail_id, ingredients_id, and the quantity.

EDIT 1:
There are many things you could do, for example when you are creating your form in your route, you could send to it your cocktail_id, and then when you're creating your form, you'll search for all instances of cocktail_id in your Table 3; and create a new (or set of) field(s) for each result. And the moment the user pressing 'add ingredient', you could send them

```
def createForm(cocktail_id):
    
    class FormClass(FlaskForm):
        # put your non dynamic fields here
        pass
    # add in your fields that are dependent on how many ingredients 

    post_variables_list = []

    # find all table 3 results for given cocktail
    table3_objects = Table3.query.filter_by(id=cocktail_id).all()
    for table3_object in table3_objects:
        setattr(FormClass, f'ingredientname_{table3_object.table3_id}', StringField('Ingredient Name', default=table3_object.ingredient_name))

        post_variables_list.append(f'ingredientname_{table3_object.table3_id}')

    return FormClass(), post_variables_list


@app.route('/example_route/<int:cocktail_id>')
def example_route(cocktail_id):

     form, post_variables_list = createForm(cocktail_id)
     if request.method=='POST':
        submit_dictionary = {}
        submit_dictionary = form.data

        for current_variable in post_variables_list:
            fieldname, table3_id = current_variable.split('_')
        
            # find existing object, that you can create by redirecting to a different route 
            # which just creates a new table 3 entry, which is associated w/ this cocktail each time you
            # press add ingredient and then redirects you to here
            table3_object = db.session.query(Table3).filter(Table3.id==table3_id).first()
            if fieldname = 'name':
                table3_object.name = submit_dictionary[current_variable]
            # could have other conditions here for other fields

            db.session.add(table3_object)
            db.session.commit()
            

# route which just creates a new empty ingredient
@app.route('create_new_empty_ingredient/int:cocktail_id')
def create_new_empty_ingredient(cocktail_id):

    # create new entry in table 3
    table3_object = Table3 (
        cocktail_id = cocktail_id
    )
    db.session.add(table3_object)
    db.session.commit()

    # redirect back to example_route
    return redirect(url_for('example_route', cocktail_id=cocktail_id))
```

Comment: My problem does not concern the database, where I have a table for cocktails, one for ingredients and a third table which stores the recipes as 'cocktail_id, ingredient_id, milliliters'. I don't know how to send to Flask a non pre-defined number or fields, containing (for each field) the ingredient_id and the relative milliliters.

Comment: Can you provide your flask wtform class in your question, 
and also your template logic for your form?

I know that I'm capable of answering your question, because I do these kind of relationships all the time but I don't fully understand your scenario by just reading your description.

Comment: Can you describe the mechanism you're using to 'add ingredient'? Oh so you don't know how to send it from your template to your route? Okay show me what you're doing upon pressing 'add ingredient'. Are they selecting the ingredient they want to add before pressing add? Or is add ingredient giving them a new row which has a dropdown of possible selections?

Comment: I've edited my question and added more details, and also read your code, thank you. But the problem is not about "adding a new ingredient in the database", this is done by another form. Here I'm creating a new drink, and "attaching" to this drink a list of 'ingredient_id' that already exists in the database. I just don't know how to pass those to the backend via WTForms. Hope my explaination make sense.

Comment: There are 2 ways to make your wtform dynamic that I've used. 
FieldList/FormFields or using this 'setattr' method I use in my solution above. 

I think you misunderstand my solution because even after reading your updated comments I think my solution is valid. When I wrote comment "# route which just creates a new empty ingredient", I don't mean that it's creating a new ingredient. But that's it's creating a new row in your 3rd table. which saves a new ingredient to your current cocktail. For example, Vodka and Gin would have their own rows in table 3.

Comment: My solution will grow your form, an extra field for each row in table 3, which is associated w/ this cocktail. for each unique ingredient who's relationships has been created by saving it here in table 3. Each new form field will allow you to display this additional ingredient.